# Troubles with laying out memory for use by OpenGL (glBufferSubData help needed)

Tags: c++, opengl, memory

So today I wanted to learn how I can use a Vector2 & Color class to send data to OpenGL with pretty clean looking syntax.

The plan is this.

```cpp
/*
Vector2 (8 bytes)
Color (16 bytes)
Vector2 + Color = 24 bytes
    
How can memory be laid out like this?

{Vector2, Color},
{Vector2, Color},
{Vector2, Color}
*/
```

So I have my two arrays of data.

```
Vector2 vertices[] = {
    Vector2(0.0f, 0.5f),
    Vector2(0.5f, -0.5f),
    Vector2(-0.5f, -0.5f)
};

// colors would be mapped to there respective indexes in the vertices array (i.e colors[0] is mapped to vertices[0])
Color colors[] = {
    Color(1.0f, 0.3f, 0.3f),
    Color(0.3f, 1.0f, 0.3f),
    Color(0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f)
};
```

I was able to get a regular triangle rendering at the correct points,
[image]

but sending over the color data has been pretty difficult for me to pull off.

The result I currently get is this.
[image]

Here's a snippet of the code.

```cpp
    // positions on screen
    Vector2 vertices[] = {
        Vector2(0.0f, 0.5f),
        Vector2(0.5f, -0.5f),
        Vector2(-0.5f, -0.5f)
    };

    // colors for each position
    Color colors[] = {
        Color(1.0f, 0.3f, 0.3f),
        Color(0.3f, 1.0f, 0.3f),
        Color(0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f)
    };

    // create vertex and array buffers (each bound automatically)
    unsigned int vertexArray = createVertexArray();
    unsigned int vertexBuffer = createBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);

    // allocate the data
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices) + sizeof(colors), nullptr, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // fill up allocated memory 
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vector2) * i, sizeof(Vector2), &vertices[i]);
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (sizeof(Vector2) + sizeof(Color)) * (i + 1), sizeof(Color), &colors[i]);
    }

    // set up vertex attributes
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, sizeof(Vector2) + sizeof(Color), nullptr);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, sizeof(Vector2) + sizeof(Color), (const void*)( sizeof(Vector2) ));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add 1 vertex and 1 color alternately to the buffer:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{    
    GLintptr offsetV = i * (sizeof(Vector2) + sizeof(Color)); 
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, offsetV, sizeof(Vector2), &vertices[i]);
 
    GLintptr offsetC = offsetV + sizeof(Vector2); 
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, offsetC, sizeof(Color), &colors[i]);
}
```